# Eliminar circulos de circular packing con d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, d3-v4.js

estoy haciendo un  proyecto con d3.js pero tengo un problema, quiero realizar una reduccion de elementos en un circular packing, pero al aplicar el filtro, los circulos se duplican, no se eliminan del todo bien, o se crean otros nuevos dentro de ellos. Estoy seguro que el error esta en el data join.
Aqui esta el codigo: https://github.com/ymotomy/ProyectoInfoVis/tree/main/Visualizacion

Especificamente en el archivo main.js, aproximadamente linea 519 en adelante
Seria de mucho alivio que me pudiesen ayudar